# Unable to do "git checkout main"

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-commit, git-checkout

Whenever I am trying to run:

```
git checkout main
```

I am getting an error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    README.md
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I have tried doing the following steps:

1. ```
    git rm --cached README.md
    git checkout main
   ```

   Didn't work.
2. ```
    git add -all
    git commit -m "initial commit"
    git checkout main
   ```

   Still the same output.

Comment: @Joe, thanks! This link helped me!!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to keep README.md change:

```
git add README.md
git reset HEAD --hard
git checkout main
```

If you want to keep README.md change:

```
git add README.md
git commit -m "Your commit message"
git checkout main
```

or you want edit it at main branch later:

```
git add README.md
git stash
git checkout main
git stash pop
```

Comment: Will `git reset HEAD --hard` remove an untracked `README.md` file?

Comment: @Joe Thanks! You should add it first, then reset will work. I will edit answer.

Comment: BTW, if your git version is 2.23 or later, i recommend new command: `git switch <branch>`

Comment: `add`/`reset --hard` is a fairly confusing way to achieve `rm`.

Comment: I think there is a README on main, and here is one, too. But the file modified, cause can't switch branch. If we use `git rm` or with `--cached` flag, git will delete file or make the file untracked. This result may not be what we want so I decide the `reset` to make file unchanged.

Comment: If `git` says "untracked working tree files", then no, there isn't a file on this branch. Use `rm README.md` to clear it out.

Comment: Oh, i understand what you mean. Because the file is untracked, we can directly `rm` it if we don't want to keep it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `git checkout -f master`

Also check branch name. The default branch name in Git is master.

Comment: Ok..But exactly how to check it?